# Ajax response Too long

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Ajax response gets too long while detecting proxy and VPN connection in  PHP

**PHP CODE**

```
     $ports = array(8080,80,81,1080,6588,8000,3128,553,554,4480);
    $ips=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     foreach($ports as $port) {
  if (@fsockopen($ips, $port, $errno, $errstr, 30)) {


    die("You are using a proxy!");
    }
}
```

**AJAX CODE**

```
 $('.kink').click(function(){  
 var p='kolo';
var fata={page:p};
$.ajax({  
type: 'POST',  
url: '/iptest/', 
data: fata,
success: function(data) {

}

})
 });
```

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: I am confused by the notion that the remote address listening on a particular port somehow indicates that it's a proxy.

Comment: `I am confused by the notion that the remote address listening on a particular port somehow indicates that it's a proxy`...indeed. And it's also confusing to think why that would be a problem. Proxy servers are a completely normal and standard part of many environments.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean with 'too long': a request or script timeout.

Each call to `fsockopen` can take up to 30 seconds, in your code. Test if you run into php execution time limit, if that's the case, split up the testing of ports into multiple calls. For example calles like `POST /iptest/?port=8080`. You can also look into [set_time_limit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php). If php request executes just fine and can run for let's say 10x 30 seconds, then adjust the timout of your ajax call with the `timeout` option.